# is it possible to unlock more than 3 device with a single account

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have registered 3devices already in my developer account,

Is it possible to unlock a new device with that same account,

Can i remove older device to unlock new device, is it possible?

Can anybody help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your account extended to support being able to unlock more than 3 devices but you have to [raise a support ticket](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=293697) to request the change.

As part of your request you should specify how many more you want and explain why you need them.
I've used "to unlock more devices for testing" or "to provide devices to clients so they can see app progress" in the past.

There is a limit of 20 devices that can be unlocked per account.
However, if you are working with Microsoft on a specific project that requires it they, apparently, can alter the account to unlock for more. But you need approval from a Microsoft account holder to get this.

The limit is on the number of devices that can be unlocked at any one time.
When a device is unregistered it becomes unable to have apps side-loaded on to it or to run any apps that were side-loaded previously.

[image: Lots of unlocked devices on one account]

Comment: Hi Matt, whats that 20 device per account, is that include the removed and added devices? can u please tell me more clearly,,

Answer (score 0):

You can "unregister" old device and "register" new by standart tool.

Unregister old device:
[image: unregister old device]

Comment: You can also request the ability to unlock more devices.

Answer (score 0):

Sign into your dev account using your developer credentials, select account and go to the phones tab, see screenshot [image]

You are not able to have more than 3 unlocked devices unless you interope unlcok your phone and mod it to allow a n infinite number of unsigned apps.

Comment: can u give me link for above screenshot?, to remove device from developer unlock list, is it available if i am using simple microsoft live id to unlock 2 devices?